# Removing an object from a javascript list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I currently have a list of objects in javascript indexed by a key:

```
var list = [];
list['a'] = [];
list['a'].push({obj: 'test'});
list['a'].push({obj: 'test2'});

list['b'] = [];
list['b'].push({obj: 'test'});
list['b'].push({obj: 'test2'});
```

I would list to remove the entry based on the key (a/b)

I have tried the following:

```
for(var x in list) { delete list[x]; }
```

that works but it actually leaves an undefined entry in the list.

I have also tried splicing the array, but that does not seems to work in this case.

Any thoughts on how to remove the entry in javascript or jQuery?

Thanks.

**The Fix:**

After reading some of the comments, i was able to better understand what my list is consistent of. Therefor, i was able to do the removal by doing the following:

```
delete list.b;
```

I'm not sure if my list is best way to organize my structure, but doing a delete on the list and treating it like an object property did the trick.

Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Are you sure your `list` is an object not an array?

Comment: You are correct, it is an array of objects.

Comment: Then your array definition in the question is broken.

Comment: @Dani Do you want to reset a or b, or do you want to remove an element from a or b ?

Comment: information has been so badly put together here that confusion is abounding. Latest code isn't an array at all regardless if you initially define it as one. `list['a']` makes it an object since javascript has no associative arrays

Comment: Well not really, arrays are already objects in js, but you'll see it and cry for help only when you'll use a `for..in` loop with it. That's awful, but technically an array can have a property holding another array, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Expanding on @aduch's comment, although it might be an array it doesn't contain any array *elements* (`.length` would be 0) - it contains 2 array *object properties*.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume `list` is an object, not an array.

If you want to reset `a` or (or `b` it's done the same way)

```
list.a.length = 0;
```

If you want to delete an element from `a` at a known index (let `index`)

```
list.a.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to add the elements to the array object as *object properties* and not as *array elements*. You can verify this by inspecting the value of `list.length` (will be 0).

So when doing something such as the following:

```
function removeProperty(id) {
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      delete list[id];
  }
}

removeProperty('a');
```

it's really the same as:

```
delete list.a;
```

which is why you think it *leaves an undefined 'entry' in the 'list'*.

You'll need to use a literal object instead:

```
var list = {};

list['a'] = [];
...

list['b' = [];
...
```

which would allow you to use `delete` and have it behave as you expect. Of course you'll lose the `.length` property on the array but you never had that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple prototype for the Array class

```
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    // Helper function to remove a single element from a list if exists
    item = arguments[0]
    if (this.includes(item)) {
        index = this.indexOf(item)
        this.splice(index, 1)
     }
}

// Now we can call
myList.remove(YourObject)
```

The above code will add the `remove` method to all your lists, so this will help you not just for objects but also strings, integers, or any data type

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = {1: [{},{}], 2: [{},{}]};

function removeProperty(obj, prop){
    if(obj[prop]){
        delete obj[prop];
    }
}

removeProperty(list,"1");

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Uhm, why do you need loop here? `if (x in obj) { delete ... }`

Comment: Yep :-) But the thing is that OP has an array :-)

Comment: OP's list is not valid. If it is made into an object like var list = {1: [{},{}], 2: [{},{}] }, delete should work.

Comment: @RajkumarMadhuram Did OP edit his question?  I copied that list variable from the question.

Comment: Yep they did, unsuccessfully though )

Comment: @Dani: your code currently is syntactically incorrect

Comment: When did SO stop showing edits?  I can't see the revisions on the question.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox: if it's done until 5 minutes passed by the original author - it's not tracked (at least there is no public link available)

Comment: I have updated the question to better explain the question and the issue i'm running into.  Although removeProperty removes the element but it keeps an undefined entry in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If this quote:

> I would list to remove the entry based on the key (a/b)

means you would like to select the list to consider based off the key (a/b), then remove elements in the list (or all of them), you can try this:

```
var list = [];
list['a'] = [];
list['a'].push({obj: 'test4'});
list['a'].push({obj: 'test5'});

list['b'] = [];
list['b'].push({obj: 'test'});
list['b'].push({obj: 'test2'});

var toRemove = 'test4';
var removeFrom = "a";

var consideredList;
for (var prop in list) {
  if (prop == removeFrom) {
    consideredList = list[prop];
  }
}

//Remove everything from the considered list
consideredList.splice(0, consideredList.length);

//Remove based off value, if you know the property  name
// for(var pos in consideredList) {
//   if(consideredList[pos].obj == toRemove) {
//     consideredList.splice(pos, 1);
//   }
// }
```

I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBZi1yFl1SYyQlEAXgco?p=preview) of a few different cases (check the script.js file). There seems to be a bit of confusion on what you are after and hopefully this is helpful to you somehow. Good luck.